# UIActivityViewIndicator in browser while loading and if string contains http:// remove it

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview, uiactivity

I'm creating a simple web browser as an exercise.

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender {
NSString *query = [_urlField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",query]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

I would like it to know how I could add a UIActivityIndicator while loading my webView.

**2nd question:**

Is it possible to remove the http:// if the user enters it? I know you can do this in PHP like this:

```
if(strpos($URL, "http://") !== false)
```

How could I use it in Objective C?

Thanks you all for helping me.

Comment: Please in the future, separate your questions.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here. I'll do it in the future.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to point it out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first questions, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311088/how-implement-a-uiactivityindicatorview-when-the-uiwebview-is-loading-iphone-o).

And the second:

```
NSString* urlWithoutProtocol = [urlWithProtocol stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks @NSAddict. But what if I want to add various NSStrings to replace items.. I needed to remove my first line of code to get it working and get urlWithProtocol into urlField.text. I also edited NSString *query

Comment: What do you mean? Can you make an example?

Comment: I used this code 
NSString *query = [_urlField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];

But now I want also to remove @"www." into @""

Comment: Then just do [urlWithProtocol stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"www." withString:@""] again

Comment: But what should I place before that line of code? I cant use NSString *query again..

Comment: of course you can :)
query = [query stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"www." withString:@""];

Comment: you must not define the query variable again

Comment: "NSString *query" says to the compiler to make a variable which should hold a NSString object reference. If you have defined it once in a certain scope, you can never define it again. Then you can just use it's name to get or set it.

Comment: Feel free to upvote answers if they helped you, users earn points like this ;) lol

Comment: I tried to vote you up but I don't have enough reputation.. Perhaps if you vote me up ;-)

Comment: haha, it's not going to be enough. Voted you up though. thanks

Comment: NSString *query = [urlWithProtocol stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://www." withString:@""];
query = [urlWithProtocol stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];

Comment: Because there might be other parts of the url with "www."
Like http://www.ilijatovilo.ch/?redirect=www.someotherwebsite.com

Comment: @USer Begininning: A very good learning approach.As asking questions....reallyy very good..too  for NSAddict up vote for such a nice conversation.