# Hide and show UIButton via UIWebView

Tags: ios, json, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How implement a UIActivityIndicatorView when the UIWebView is Loading? (iPhone ObjC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311088/how-implement-a-uiactivityindicatorview-when-the-uiwebview-is-loading-iphone-o)

A part of my app allows users to 'Update' a part of the application, they press an 'Update' `UIButton`, and this loads a PHP script in a `UIWebView`, however the script takes around 2 minutes to load and during this time I want the 'Update' button to hide, and to show again when the webpage has finished loading.

What would be the best method of doing this?

I have this so far:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webUpdate {
    [btnUpdate setHidden:YES];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webUpdate {
    [btnUpdate setHidden:NO];
}
```

Solved using this:

```
NSString *myUrl = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

    if ([myUrl isEqualToString:@"http://www.website.com/finalpage.php"]) {
        [btnUpdate setHidden:NO];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIWebViewDelegate` has call backs  so you can keep track of your webviews' progress.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        [btnUpdate setHidden:YES];
    }

 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
               NSLog(@"Loading: %@", [request URL]);
               return YES;
            }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
               NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
                    (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
    [btnUpdate setHidden:NO];
            }


- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
               NSLog(@"didFail: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
                    (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
    [btnUpdate setHidden:NO];
    //alert
            }
```

Comment: Please check my updated question as I have added this but still not working.

Comment: @Jack put some breakpoints, nslogs and see what's going on. Does it fire or not?

Comment: I have it working now, however UIWebView is loading a PHP which contains redirects and the webViewDidFinishLoad is being called before the php file has actually finished processing. Is there a way of checking the URL before showing the button again to check the php script has finished?

Comment: try my edited answer, if its not working try to modify it

Comment: Getting there... NSLog says still loading:YES but the button appears...

Comment: I added an if statement, not it appears that still loading never goes to NO...

Comment: Solved see my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

for callback methods for the UIWebView. Look specifically at

```
– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
```

You can try hiding or disabling the update button when the webview starts loading and then enable it when it finishes or if an error occurs.

Edit:
You can check current URL with

```
NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];
```

And you should maybe increment an int property in webViewDidStartLoad and then decrement it in webViewDidFinishLoad so that you know when you are at the end of your loads.

Comment: My PHP file contains redirects as well, would this still work?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I believe if the WebView starts a redirect it may call the -webViewDidStartLoad again, so basically you will have to keep track of starts and finishes to know when the php file is complete

Comment: Have you set your class as the webview delegate? Can you verify that those methods are being called.

Comment: I have it working now, however UIWebView is loading a PHP which contains redirects and the webViewDidFinishLoad is being called before the php file has actually finished processing. Is there a way of checking the URL before showing the button again to check the php script has finished?

Comment: I edited my answer above

Answer (score 0):

I think the uiwebview has a callback function when your page has loaded. You have to read the docs about this